# Manipulation of matrix in fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I have matrix and array.  I need to multiply their value. Then find the line with the maximum sum , and bring its number and value . Help me to understand

```
real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: startArr
  real, allocatable:: x(:) , maxArr

 do i = 1,4
        do k=1,4
            startArr(1,i)*x(k)
            startArr(2,i)*x(k)
            startArr(3,i)*x(k)
            startArr(4,i)*x(k)
        end do
 end do


    S = startArr(1,1)+ startArr(1,2) + startArr(1,3) + startArr(1,4)
    D = startArr(2,1)+ startArr(2,2) + startArr(2,3) + startArr(2,4)
    M = startArr(3,1)+ startArr(3,2) + startArr(3,3) + startArr(3,4)
    K = startArr(4,1)+ startArr(4,2) + startArr(4,3) + startArr(4,4)


    maxArr = (S,D,M,K)
    max = S
    do i = 1,4
        if(maxArr(i)>max)
            max = maxArr(i)
    end do
```

Comment: What is your question?  You have some code you don't understand; the code doesn't work; there's something missing; you don't know an algorithm?

Comment: francescalus, 
I wrote how I think . But I do not know how it is write on fortan. And my algorithm is correct?

Comment: From what code you have I guess you have some, but very little working knowledge of Fortran.  Stack Overflow perhaps isn't a good place to be learning the language.  That said, if you can break your problem down and consider [mcve] we may be able to help.  As your question stands we'll essentially have to write the whole code for you to meet your specification (which few people are willing to do except for the most interesting problems).

Comment: francescalus, ok , I understand, but my algorithm is correct?
or I can do without additional array?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on either your algorithm for multiplication is right or not. you have to check it with your mathematics however some parts of your code is wrong. I tried to correct them. this is my own version in Compaq Fortran.

```
    program matrix_Manipulation
implicit none
real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: startArr,MultipliedArray
real, allocatable:: x(:) , sumLine(:)
real:: maxValue
integer::i,k

 allocate(startArr(4,4),x(4),sumLine(4),MultipliedArray(4,4))

  startArr(1,1)=1 
  startArr(2,1)=2 
  startArr(3,1)=3 
  startArr(4,1)=4 
  startArr(1,2)=5 
  startArr(2,2)=6 
  startArr(3,2)=7 
  startArr(4,2)=8 
  startArr(1,3)=9 
  startArr(2,3)=10
  startArr(3,3)=11
  startArr(4,3)=12
  startArr(1,4)=13
  startArr(2,4)=14
  startArr(3,4)=15
  startArr(4,4)=16

  x(1)=2  
  x(2)=0.5
  x(3)=8  
  x(4)=1  

 do i = 1,4
        do k=1,4
            MultipliedArray(1,i)=startArr(1,i)*x(k)
            MultipliedArray(1,i)=startArr(2,i)*x(k)
            MultipliedArray(1,i)=startArr(3,i)*x(k)
            MultipliedArray(1,i)=startArr(4,i)*x(k)
        end do
 end do


    sumLine(1) = sum(MultipliedArray(1,1:4))
    sumLine(2) = sum(MultipliedArray(2,1:4))
    sumLine(3) = sum(MultipliedArray(3,1:4))
    sumLine(4) = sum(MultipliedArray(4,1:4))

    maxValue = MAXVAL(sumLine)



end program matrix_Manipulation
```

the 'MAXVAL' is a built-in function to mind the maximum element of an array or matrix. That is in Comaq Fortran and it might be a different funtion in gFortran or ther compiler.

Comment: maxval is a standard intrinsic